# JavaScript retrieves data before Primefaces AJAX event call has been finished

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

In a TabView primefaces component, on tabChange I want to do a ajax-call to update the bean data in the bean that then needs to be processed by javascript (some charts).

The problem I experience is that the data gets updated correctly with my ajax call, but the javascript that uses the data is retrieved before it has been updated by the ajax-call.

This is the primeface-component with the ajax-call on the event of tabChange.

```
<p:tabView>
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{bean.onTabChange}" />
        <p:tab title="Tab 1" id="tab1">
                //chart1
        </p:tab>  

        <p:tab title="Tab 2" id="tab2">
               //chart2    
        </p:tab>  

        <p:tab title="Tab 3" id="tab3">
              //chart3
        </p:tab>  
</p:tabView>
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
function renderTheChart(tabIndex) { 
    var categories= [];
    var categories= [];

    <ui:repeat var="data" value="#{bean.dataList}">
        categories[categories.length] = "#{data.id}";
        values[values.length] = #{data.value};
    </ui:repeat>


    renderChart(values, categories, tabIndex);          
}
```

To know when to call the javascript to update the component I tried the Client Side Callback.

```
<p:tabView onTabChange="handleTabChange(event, index)">
```

JavaScript:

```
function handleTabChange(event, index) {
     renderTheChart(index);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is occurring is that the `onTabChange` Javascript is executing before the server postback occurs.  This is normal behavior, and while many Primefaces components have an `oncomplete` attribute, the TabView has no such attribute.

One way you can tell the Javascript to execute on return of the postback is by adding a javascript on the RequestContext.  In the action listener method `onTabChange` adding the following code will add the script to the postback.

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.execute("renderTheChart(" + tabIndex + ");");
```

Another problem you might run into though is that if you do not specify elements in the form to update from the `<p:ajax>` component then the `<ui:repeat>` tags will likely not get refreshed with the new values for `#{bean.dataList}`.  You could specify to update the form elements using the `update` attribute of the ajax component, or you can add it to the RequestContext in your action listener.

```
//update panel   
context.addPartialUpdateTarget("form:panel");
```

Comment: It works all good! Thanks for the tip with the <ui-repeat>. It did cause problems but was as you mention, solved by adding "update" in the ajax-component! thanks!

Comment: @user373455 No problem :)  If you look at Mr.J4mes answer below, it should also solve the problem with the Javascript, and it is a cleaner solution in my opinion as it requires no additional Java code.

Answer (score 3):

If you specify your JavaScript function in the attribute `onTabChange` of the `<p:tabView>` component, it would be triggered before the event you specified in the `<p:ajax>` component. As a result, your JavaScript function will receive the old data from the server before it get updated.

PrimeFaces's `<p:ajax>` component has one attribute which is `oncomplete` and this is exactly the place you should set your JavaScript function. It would be like this:

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{bean.onTabChange}" 
        oncomplete="handleTabChange(event, index);" update="someIDs"/>
```

Your JavaScript function will now be fired only when your `bean.onTabChange` function returns. Besides, don't forget to re-render any parts of page that are supposed to display new data with the `update` attribute of `<p:ajax>`.

Comment: This is the better answer.  I forgot about `<p:ajax>` having an `oncomplete` attribute already.

Comment: I didn't see this update until I tried maples solution and it worked. This does however look as maple says, neater. 
I tried it but I get an error saying "index is not defined". It does however work to send only "event". Is it possible to retrieve the index (or tab id?) from the event object?

Comment: hmm... I think you may need to store the `index` inside some hidden input and update that input `onTabChange`. Otherwise, the browser on the client side can never get the value that you are holding on the server side.